# Why do English words comprising of one syllable and ending with a y sound with a vowel preceding it correspond to German words ending in a g sound?

Tags: phonetics, sound-change

Few examples:
Lay-legen
Day-tag (I know that the d here shifted to a t due to a sound change described in Grimm's Law)
Slay-(Er)schlagen

I am aware of the fact that German and English share a common ancestor called West-Germanic, but is this particular sound correspondence due to a sound change that occured in Anglo-Frisian dialects? Because in Frisian, words seem to have undergone the same shift(day "dei"), whereas in other Germanic tongues, such as in dutch, it looks like it has kept the kept the final g sound like in German.

Comment: The "final g sound like in German" is quite variable. In standard German, final _ig_ is normally pronounced like _ich_; _Burg_ rhymes with _durch_. In Dutch, all G's are fricated in most dialects. And once a syllable has gone from _ig_ to _ich_, it's a very short step to palatalizing the fricative and reducing it to a resonant yod.

Comment: @jlawler Not *quite* … Standard pronunciation of *Burg* rhymes with *Turk* just like *Tag* rhymes with the first syllable of *Pakistan* and even the standard pronunciation of *weg* (away) rhymes with *Teck*. The standard pronunciation of *-ig* is given as /iç/ as if it were *-ich*, but not all dialects/accents participate (in Bavarian, it is /ik/). However, many accents fricativise *g* in many places to a corresponding *ch* irrespective of what standard pronunciation suggests.

Comment: As I said, quite variable. In any event, this is not a surprising result.

Comment: Since German devoices final -g, no German word ends in a g sound.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to [Old English Palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Old_English#Palatalization), the same reason modern English has "hard" and "soft" versions of the letters *g* and *c*.

Wikipedia has more details, but to summarize: in certain environments, the velar consonants `/k/` and `/g/` changed their pronunciation. `/g/` (the first sound in "get") usually ended up turning into `/j/` (the first sound in "yes") or `/d͡ʒ/` (the first sound in "gem"), depending on what came before it.

In this particular case, the Old English word was `/dæg/`, with a `/g/` after a front vowel `/æ/`. And in this environment, `/g/` became `/j/`, eventually spelled with the letter *y*, giving *day*. In the ancestor of modern German, these changes didn't happen, so the `/g/` stuck around, giving *Tag*.

(By the way, the different initial consonants in *day~Tag* aren't due to Grimm's Law—Grimm's Law happened back before the ancestor of German and the ancestor of English split apart. Instead, this is due to the *second Germanic consonant shift*, also known as the *High German consonant shift*, which affected the ancestor of modern German but *not* the ancestor of modern English.)